# Hadoop : java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

Am new to hadoop, Today only i started with it, 
I want to write the file to hdfs hadoop server, Am using the server hadoop 1.2.1, When i give jps command in cli am able to see all the nodes are running,

```
31895 Jps
29419 SecondaryNameNode
29745 TaskTracker
29257 DataNode
```

This is my sample client code to write the file to hdfs system

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        try {
          //1. Get the instance of COnfiguration
          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
          configuration.addResource(new Path("/data/WorkArea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1/conf/core-site.xml"));
          configuration.addResource(new Path("/data/WorkArea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
          //2. Create an InputStream to read the data from local file
          InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/local/PAYODA/hariprasanth.l/Desktop/ProjectionTest"));
          //3. Get the HDFS instance
          FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:54310"), configuration);
          //4. Open a OutputStream to write the data, this can be obtained from the FileSytem
          OutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hadoop/Hadoop_File.txt"),
          new Progressable() {  
                  @Override
                  public void progress() {
             System.out.println("....");
                  }
                        });
          try
          {
            IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, outputStream, 4096, false); 
          }
          finally
          {
            IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
            IOUtils.closeStream(outputStream);
          } 
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

My Exception while running the code,

```
java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1063)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1031)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:198)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:235)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:109)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1792)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:1826)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1808)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:265)
at com.test.hadoop.writefiles.FileWriter.main(FileWriter.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:760)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:698)
```

When i debug it, The error happens in the line when i try to connect to hdfs local server,

```
  FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:54310"), configuration);
```

As fas as I googled, It shows that am mis-matching the version,

Server version of hadoop is - 1.2.1
Client jar am using are

```
hadoop-common-0.22.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-0.22.0.jar
```

Please tell me the problem, ASAP,

If possible recommend the place where can i find the client jars for hadoop, name the jars too... please...

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Looks like hadoop services are not started properly. There is no "NameNode" service started. That might not be an issue at this point of time, but it comes once you resolve jar dependency issue. Please post your core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, and mapred-site.xml files.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the same class representation in different jar (i.e) `hadoop commons` and `hadoop core` having the same class. 
Actually I got confused of using the corresponding jars.

Finally I ended up using the `apache hadoop core`. It works like a fly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no NameNode running. Problem is with your Namenode. Did you format NameNode before starting up?

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: 2988 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar \n
3719 TaskTracker \n
3271 NameNode \n
3511 SecondaryNameNode \n
8472 Jps \n
3606 JobTracker \n
this is my jps command output

Comment: There is no problem with namenode too... Could u pls tell me the steps in configuring the eclipse part

Comment: 8486 NodeManager
7823 DataNode
8092 SecondaryNameNode
7613 NameNode
10831 Jps
8265 ResourceManager

When you run jps you should get all the above

Comment: I think you are missing datanode now

Comment: Once delete all the files in the hadoop filesystem path (hadoop.tmp.dir) in /hadoop_path/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml and save it.
Format it again now. may be this would help.